# Render dropdown for single column in DT shiny and making the table editable

Tags: r, shiny, dropdown

My goal is to have a dropdown menu in a column of datatable and make the table editable for other columns as well. 
I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215607/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny) solution for my first requirement and datatable can be edited by putting `editable = TRUE`.
I am able to do both the things separately with no issues, but I am not able to do both the things together.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectinput column in a table',
  h3("Source:", tags$a("Yihui Xie", href = "https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/")),
  DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sel')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- head(iris, 5)

  # adding column having dropdown items
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    data$species_selector[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "", choices = unique(iris$Species), width = "100px"))
  }

  ## output for data table
  output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
    data,
    escape = F,
    editable = T,
    selection = 'none',
    server = F,      # we need it to be TRUE.
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE)
    ,callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    ,rownames = F
  )

  # saving the proxy of table 
  proxy = dataTableProxy('foo')

  text <- reactive({
    # browser()
    (sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
  })

  output$sel = renderPrint({
    # data$species_selector[1]
    text()
  })

  # this chunk is for update the table for changes done in ui. "This is a must have"
  observeEvent(input$foo_cell_edit, {
    info = input$foo_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1  # column index offset by 1
    v = info$value
    data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, data[i, j])
    # replacing the data in the proxy
    replaceData(proxy, data, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I put `server = T` I can edit the table with no issues but I can not get the selected values of dropdown menu (which I need). And when I put `server = F` then I get the selected values of dropdown but then when I try to edit my table it shows error as ***"DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"*** 
Any help or direction is highly appreciated.
 **Note:** I know these both operations are very easy in rhandsontable, I am not using it because it has other limitations like search button, conditional formatting etc.