# Embed column with mixed numericInput and selectInput in DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to add a column to a DT that accepts either selectInput or numericInput, depending on the variable.
For example, given the following DF:

```
df1 <- tibble(
 
  var1 = sample(letters[1:3],10,replace = T),
  var2 = runif(10, 0, 2),
  id=paste0("id",seq(1,10,1))
)

DF=gather(df1, "var", "value", -id)
```

I would like to create an extra col in the DF (using `DT`), with selectInput for `var1` (choices= letters[1:3]) and numericInput for `var2`.
I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215607/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny) a great example for implementing selectInput, however I am not sure how it might be combined with numericInput.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adapted version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215607/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny).

Instead of `gather`, using `pivot_longer` which is recommended in latest version of `tidyr`. In addition, when creating the inputs for the new `selector` column, check the variable `name`. If it is `var1` use a `selectInput`, otherwise use `numericInput`.

Otherwise, should work in a similar fashion.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  var1 = sample(letters[1:3],10,replace = T),
  var2 = runif(10, 0, 2),
  id=paste0("id",seq(1,10,1))
)

# gather is retired, switch to pivot_longer
DF = pivot_longer(df1, cols = -id, names_to = "name", values_to = "value", values_transform = list(value = as.character))

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'selectInput or numericInput column in a table',
  DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sel')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
    if (DF$name[i] == "var1") {
      DF$selector[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "", choices = unique(df1$var1), width = "100px"))
    } else {
      DF$selector[i] <- as.character(numericInput(paste0("sel", i), "", NULL, width = "100px"))
    }
  }
  output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
    DF, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
  )
  output$sel = renderPrint({
    str(sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```