# How to add checkbox and dropdown list to DT table in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

i am investigating the problem to embed checkbox and dropdown list into separate columns of DT datatable. Now I can populate only one column with checkbox or dropdown list.

Right now, i have managed to find nice examples of checkbox or dropdown list via callback option.
But i have not managed to find the example where i can embed both of elements into separate columns of the same DT table.

I have found nice example of dropdown list (see the answer section):
[Example of dropdown list in DT table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215607/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny).

I would be grateful if someone could make a hint how to add the extra column with checkboxes in above mentioned example (besides dropdown list). I am not skilled in JS.

**UPDATED:**
I have tried this version (added checkbox line) but the string is not generated while selecting the dropdown list as in the example specified above

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectinput column in a table',
  h3("Source:", tags$a("Yihui Xie", href = "https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/")),
  DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sel')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- head(iris, 5)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    data$species_selector[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "", choices = unique(iris$Species), width = "100px"))
    data$species_checkbox[i] <- as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("sel_checkbox_", i), ""))
  }
   
  output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
    data, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
                  });
                  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
                )
  output$sel = renderPrint({
    str(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) input[[paste0("sel", i)]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the problem you encounter, exactly?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I can add or checkbox column or dropdown list column via callback option (JS injection). But i want to have one column with checkbox and the other with dropdownlist. but i dont know how to make it in a DT table.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent i have attached my version. I have managed to visualize checkboxes in the separate column (data$species_checkbox[i]) but lost the string reactivity as in the example https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(),
  
  # Main panel with the table
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("myTable")
  )
)

dat <- head(iris, 5)
dat$species_selector <- vapply(1:5, function(i) {
  as.character(
    selectInput(
      paste0("sel", i), label = NULL, choices = unique(iris$Species), selectize = FALSE
    )
  )
}, character(1))
dat$species_checkbox <- vapply(1:5, function(i) {
  as.character(
    checkboxInput(
      paste0("sel_checkbox_", i), label = NULL
    )
  )
}, character(1))


server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$myTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, 
      escape = FALSE,
      select = "none",
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        ),
        preDrawCallback = 
          JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = 
          JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    print(input$sel1)
    print(input$sel_checkbox_1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane Laurent. It works fine for me.